# Vlookup dynamic range reference from a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am inserting a vlookup formula in a range of cells. The formula however has a dynamic reference in it, and I am having hard time in constructing it correctly.

**Here is my code:**

```
Sheets("Count").Activate

Dim myValue As Date
myValue = InputBox("Please enter the date you want to update")
Sheets("Count").Range("A1").Value = myValue

Dim ra As Range, raEnd As Range
Dim date1 As Date
date1 = Range("A1")

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:=date1 _
                    , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , LookAt:=xlPart _
                    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                    , SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                    , MatchCase:=False _
                    , SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Date not found, check the format.")

    Else

        Dim Lastrow As Long, rng As Range
        Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range(ra.Offset(1, 0), Cells(Lastrow, ra.Column))

        Dim endrow As Long, i As Long, lcol As Integer, startcells As Range
        lcol = Sheets("Count").Range("B1").Value
        endrow = Sheets("Input").Cells(Rows.Count, lcol).End(xlUp).Row
        i = 6
        Set startcells = Sheets("Input").Cells(i, lcol)

        Sheets("Input").Activate

        Dim xrnge As Range, s
        Set xrnge = Range(startcells, Cells(endrow, lcol))
        s = xrnge.Address

        Sheets("Count").Activate
        rng.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B8,'" & "input" & "'!s,1,0),"""")"

    End If

End Sub
```

The part that I cannot make work is

```
rng.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B8,'" & "input" & "'!s,1,0),"""")"
```

**I think I am almost there because in the range where I want to insert the formula looks like this:**

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B20;Input!s;1;0);"")
```

Could you help me to figure out why it shows s and not the range itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want `s` to hold a range address, and `input` to be a static sheet reference. In that case, you should write your formula as so:

```
rng.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B8,input!" & s & ",1,0),"""")"
```

Say `s` holds the address for range `S3:S50` the result in cell will be:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B8,Input!$S$3:$S$50,1,0),"")
```

Which will be a working formula as expected.

Comment: Hi @plutian, yes, correct! and it works :) so It is only about the synthax? do you know a source where I can check these kind of things? Anyway thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It's a matter of good concatenated strings. If you not sure about the end result use `Debug.Print`

Comment: @G_TTI there aren't many available online, as most people using VBA will prefer doing all calculations with VBA instead of formula altogether. However, playing around with the macro recorder reveals quite a lot of interesting things.

Comment: Great! Thanks :)